# How to remove double quote from json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove double quote from only data node from json string.

current json:

```
[{"name":"Labor Shortage Index","data":["0.2","0.5","0.5","1.8"]}]
```

So after remove double quote json will be:

```
[{"name":"Labor Shortage Index","data":[0.2,0.5,0.5,1.8]}]
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Parse the JSON string (if it really is a JSON string; if it's a JavaScript object, then you can skip that step) then find the strings that look like numbers and convert them with `parseFloat()`.

Comment: How does the data get in the JSON? Do you manage that, or would you like to just convert it? If the latter, you can use `parseFloat()` on the array's elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With applying `Number` for every element.

```js
var object = [{ "name": "Labor Shortage Index", "data": ["0.2", "0.5", "0.5", "1.8"] }];
object[0].data = object[0].data.map(Number);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Parse the JSON
2. Loop over the `data` array
3. Overwrite each value with the result of calling `parseFloat` on it
4. Stringify back to JSON

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
var obj = [{"name":"Labor Shortage Index","data":["0.2","0.5","0.5","1.8"]}];
obj = obj.map(function(value){
   value.data = value.data.map(function(innerValue){ return parseFloat(innerValue); });
   return value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One answer would be to use an array map to parse the data node array:

```js
var parsedData = data.map(function(num){
    return parseFloat(num);
});
```

See [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).